# How to auto-size a DevExpress TcxGrid

Tags: delphi, autosize, tcxgrid

I've created a table from a `TcxGrid` with a simple table view. The data is being poked into the table using `DataController.Values[n,m]` as a simple string and I have some 10 columns that will show various string widths.

The problem that I'm having is getting a table that has a horizontal scroll bar AND has auto-sized its columns. If I set `CellAutoWidth` true this fits all columns into the display width (with no scroll bar) but if I set it false, I get a scroll bar but columns of my default width and my data strings are truncated.

Could some kind person tell me how to get a horizontal scroll bar AND get each column to adjust its width to fit its max data width please?

Thanks
Brian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe it's enough to call `YourGridView.ApplyBestFit` instead of using `CellAutoWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set columns `BestFitMaxWidth` and `MinWidth` property and make sure you have the width of the Datasets `TField` also set (if you are using DataSets).
Then, you can call `YourGridView.ApplyBestFit`;